# Dependencies conflict with react@17.0.2 @apollo/react-common@3.1.4

Tags: reactjs, npm, apollo

I am using @apollo in my react project and I keep getting this error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @apollo/react-common@3.1.4
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @apollo/client@3.6.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@apollo/client
npm ERR!     @apollo/client@"^3.6.8" from the root project
npm ERR!     @apollo/client@"latest" from @apollo/react-components@4.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@apollo/react-components
npm ERR!       @apollo/react-components@"^4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@apollo/react-hooks)
npm ERR!   18 more (@emotion/react, @material-ui/core, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from @apollo/react-common@3.1.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@apollo/react-common
npm ERR!   @apollo/react-common@"^3.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   @apollo/react-common@"^3.1.4" from @apollo/react-ssr@3.1.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@apollo/react-ssr
npm ERR!     @apollo/react-ssr@"^3.1.5" from react-apollo@3.1.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-apollo
npm ERR!       react-apollo@"^3.1.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   5 more (@apollo/react-hooks, react-apollo, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0" from @apollo/react-common@3.1.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@apollo/react-common
npm ERR!     @apollo/react-common@"^3.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     @apollo/react-common@"^3.1.4" from @apollo/react-ssr@3.1.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/@apollo/react-ssr
npm ERR!       @apollo/react-ssr@"^3.1.5" from react-apollo@3.1.5
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-apollo
npm ERR!         react-apollo@"^3.1.5" from the root project
npm ERR!     5 more (@apollo/react-hooks, react-apollo, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/runner/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-06-17T09_09_33_753Z-debug-0.log
make: *** [Makefile:35: node_modules] Error 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

I tried to use the `--legacy-peer-deps` but in vain.
JFY, I am using these dependencies

- "@apollo/client": "^3.6.8"
- "@apollo/react-common": "^3.1.4"
- "@apollo/react-components": "^4.0.0"
- "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0"
- "react": "^17.0.2"

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade your react version to `react@"^16.8.0"` in `package.json` because `@apollo/react-common@3.1.4` reports is incompatible with 17. You must wait until they upgrade or remove the package.